# Send large string using python socket

Tags: python, tcp, tcl, python-sockets

There is a function receive_file which sends a string with a tcl command included encoded data to a server via socket. If i send a small file of roughly 100 KB or less it goes through the whole process without any problems. But with a filesize larger than that it only gives me a timeout. Is there a better way to send the data than that?

```
def connect(self):
    self.S = socket.socket()                        # Create socket (for TCP)
    self.S.connect((self.host, self.port))          # Connect to aRTist
    self.S.settimeout(self.timeout)
    self.listen(0)
    return self

def send(self, command, msgType="RESULT"):
    c = command + '\n'
    self.S.sendall(c.encode())
    return self.listen(msgType=msgType)

def listen(self, command_no=1, msgType="RESULT"):
    answer = ""
    stop = False
    if (command_no == 0):
        self.S.settimeout(0.2)
    while (not stop):# and ("SUCCESS" not in total) and ("ERROR" not in total):     # Solange server antwortet und nicht "SUCCESS" enthält
        try:
            msg = self.S.recv(self.bufferSize).decode()
            
        except BaseException as e:
            err = e.args[0]
            if err == "timed out":
                #print("Timeout\n")
                answer += "RESULT Timeout\n"
                stop = True
                continue
        else:
            if ("SUCCESS" in msg):
                answer += msg
                stop = True
                continue
            elif ("ERROR" in msg):
                answer += msg
                stop = True
                #global error
                self.error = self.error + 1 
                continue
            elif ("PROGRESS" in msg):
                try:
                    self.progress = float(msg.strip('PROGRESS '))
                except:
                    self.progress = 0
                continue
            else:
                if (command_no == 0):
                    print(msg)
                answer += msg      
    self.S.settimeout(self.timeout)
    if (msgType != "*"):
        answer = self.pick(answer, msgType)
    self.answer.update({"SUCCESS":self.pick(answer, "SUCCESS"), "RESULT":self.pick(answer, "RESULT"), "SDTOUT":self.pick(answer, "STDOUT"), "BASE64":self.pick(answer, "BASE64"), "IMAGE":self.pick(answer, "IMAGE"), "FILE":self.pick(answer, "FILE")})
    return answer

def pick(self, answer, res='RESULT'):
    picked = ""
    for a in answer.split('\n'):
        if a.find(res) == 0:
            picked += (a[1 + len(res):].strip('\r') + '\n')
    if len(picked) == 0:
            return res + ' not found.'
    return picked

def image(self, imageName):
    self.lst.clear()
    cTypes = ["bit", "char", "signed char", "unsigned char", "short", "unsigned short", "int", "unsigned int", "long", "unsigned long", "float", "double"]
    npTypes = [np.bool_, np.ubyte, np.byte, np.ubyte, np.short, np.ushort, np.intc, np.uintc, np.int_, np.uint, np.single, np.double]
    imageData = self.answer["BASE64"]
    decodedData = base64.b64decode((imageData))
    imageHeader = self.answer["IMAGE"]
    for i in imageHeader.split(","):
        self.lst.append(i)
    imType = self.lst[4]
    if imType in cTypes:
        dtype = npTypes[cTypes.index(imType)]
    im = np.frombuffer(decodedData, dtype).reshape((int(self.lst[1]),int(self.lst[2])))
    Image.fromarray(im).save(imageName)


def send_file(self, fileName):
    fileData = self.answer["BASE64"]
    decodedFile = base64.b64decode((fileData))
    artistFile = open(fileName, "wb")
    artistFile.write(decodedFile)
    artistFile.close()
    

def receive_file(self, fileName2):
    outFile = open(fileName2, "br")
    fileBytes = outFile.read()
    encBytes = base64.b64encode((fileBytes))
    encString = str(encBytes)
    encString2 = encString.lstrip("b'")
    encString3 = encString2.rstrip("'")
    com = "::RemoteControl::ReceiveFile " + encString3 + " .aRTist"
    recAnswer = self.send(com, "RESULT")
    return recAnswer
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- code that we can run locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I can see your point but the problem is you would need the whole code from the server site, which is too complex. I could give you the whole class and an example to run the code but without the server. would that help?

Comment: TCP is not message-based.  It is a byte stream and a single receive can receive any number of bytes <= buffer size. The data must be buffered and accumulated until a complete message can be extracted. See `socket.makefile` for a file-like wrapper that can handle the buffering for you.

Comment: TCP might not be message based, but there are definitely aspects where the fact that it uses messages will show up. (I'm not sure how the protocol described indicates that a complete file has arrived. It could be doing something silly like timing out at the very end.)